# Interface inheritance: is extending properties possible?

Tags: c#, inheritance, interface, properties

I want to do this:

```
interface IBase
{
    string Property1 { get; }
}

interface IInherited : IBase
{
    string Property1 { get; set; }
}
```

So that `IInherited` would have the **inherited** property `Property1` with added functionality to allow `set`.

Is that possible? What's the syntax?

**EDIT: please notice I put the word "inherited" in bold face. I am asking specifically about inheriting the property, not hiding it behind a new one.**

Comment: I think there is confusion here between inheritance of classes and inheritance of interfaces.  One interface doesn't really inherit another in the same was a class inherits another.  

All your code is saying is that IInherited also implements IBase.  The code is fine, it just raises a compiler warning because you are changing the signature of Property1 in the interface.  You can clear this with new.

Comment: As noted by many others, this syntax isn't possible, but I feel that it should be. If you use Reflection on Property1 there would be a Property1_get method and a Property1_set method, so logically it seems that you should be able to implement these separately. And the lack of being able to do so definitely causes me to duplicate code sometimes (or put up with the new keyword).

Comment: @cedd I also feel that it should be, due to the same reason you mentioned. Properties are simply disguised methods. The current design in C# is strange and causes unnecessary confusion, which is why I arrived at this SO question.

Answer (score 28):

If the fact that the only way to do this is by using the `new` keyword bothers you, then in my opinion you're thinking about interfaces wrong.

Sure, you could say that `IInherited` "inherits from" `IBase`; but what does that really **mean**? These are interfaces; they establish code contracts. By hiding the `IBase.Property1` property with `new string Property1 { get; set; }`, you are not shadowing any functionality. Thus the traditional reason that a lot of developers consider hiding to be a "bad" thing -- that it violates polymorphism -- is irrelevant in this case.

Ask yourself: what really *matters* when it comes to interfaces? They provide a guarantee of responding to certain method calls, right?

So, given the following two interfaces:

```
interface IBase
{
    string Property1 { get; }
}

interface IInherited : IBase
{
    new string Property1 { set; }
}
```

1. If an object implements `IBase`, you can read its `Property1` property.
2. If an object implements `IInherited`, you can read its `Property1` property (just as with an `IBase` implementation), and you can also write to it.

Again, there's really nothing problematic here.

Comment: You are correct, except in cases of explicit implementation.  You can have different implementations for each version, hence it is still hiding.  There is a potential that someone implementing your interface could do this, either accidentally or on purpose, so you should be careful how you consume these interfaces.  If you want to avoid this problem, and still use inheritance, then use "new", but don't add a second getter.

Comment: @Merlyn, agreed. By removing the 2nd get statement this would no longer violate the LSP.

Comment: Your code declares two *different* getters for the property. In `IInherited` you probably want to declare only `new string Property1 { set; }`. A class that implements `IInherited` can have a property with a getter and a setter and it will implement both interfaces.

Comment: @Merlyn, @Chris, and @Timwi: Good call, you guys. I will update the answer.

Comment: @Dan Tao: Any reason IInherited.Property1 is write-only?  Note that while it would make sense for attempts to read IInherited.Property1 to use IBase.Property1, that doesn't work.

Comment: @supercat: ...wait, ignore my earlier comment. Yes, there was a reason! See the comments above yours. I actually think for `IInherited.Property1` to be write-only makes sense; if you want to *read* the value there for a variable declared as `IInherited`, you would just do so by casting to `IBase` (which would be guaranteed to be safe).

Comment: @Dan Tao: Perhaps, but you create the need for an otherwise unnecessary cast.

Comment: @supercat: Well, it's debatable, right? I mean, personally, I kind of agree with you in that worrying about someone explicitly implementing two separate `get` methods and thereby "breaking" your interface design seems kind of far-fetched. At the same time, defining each `get` and `set` exactly *once* does seem a bit more "correct" in some sense. So I don't know. Anyway, Adam's answer provides the alternative approach for anyone who is interested.

Comment: @Dan Tao: The proper thing IMHO is to have an interface which will implement a read-write property shadow a read-only property of the same name, and then implement the read-only property's getter by having it read the read-write property.  I wonder why Microsoft didn't simply make a read-write property be the combination of a read-only and write-only property, and have languages use the read-only property when reading and the write-only one when writing?  Such a design would have allowed overloads of write-only properties, which could have allowed some nice performance optimizations.

Comment: @Dan Tao: For example, a class might have a property "foo" of type A, but store the data internally as type B, which has implicit typecasts to/from type A.  Under the present system, saying "thing.foo = ObjectOfTypeB" would require a conversion to type A and then back to B; if an overloaded setter were allowed, the conversion could be avoided.

Comment: The asker is right this is a problem. For example, with your solution, this will not compile: `static void M(IInherited x) { var read = x.Property1; }` The reason is that the `Property1` of `IBase` is hidden by ___another___ property also called `Property1` which is declared at a "later" point in the inheritance chain. But that latter property if `set`-only. In my opinion, the `new` modifier is fundamentally wrong since it says that we have an unrelated property. It does not "extend" the existing property. The other option with `{ get; set; }` in the `new` property is also bad, as @Timwi said.

Comment: @JeppeStigNielsen exactly, I'm surprised so many people even upvote this answer without realizing the irony here. Your explanation of the semantic ridiculousness of using "new" here is totally spot on.

Answer (score 4):

Hiding a member is violating the Liskov Substitution Principle and pretty much just shouldn't be done, ever. By hiding this member you are introducing a very difficult to locate bug since 2 different outcomes will occur depending whether you cast the object as `((IInherited).Property1)` or cast it to `((IBase).Property1)`.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liskov_substitution_principle

Comment: -1. This is not hiding in the traditional sense, since interfaces do not support polymorphism anyway.

Comment: Adam: I think Chris is correct, IFF we place his comment in the context of explicitly implemented interfaces, with different implementations.

Comment: A class that implements IInherited could be casted as a IBase with lesser rights to modify it, it is not overriding the implementation of a method, as the getter will return the same (as the two interfaces 'share' the getter implementation)

Comment: @Diego, Chris: The getter can have multiple implementations if you implement it explicitly.  You could end up with a hard to find bug if a base class you inherit from (that implements one of these interfaces) does explicit implementation.  However, Chris, I recommend you delete this since it is attracting downvotes from people who don't know any better =P

Comment: The importance of having the LSP explanation in the thread is worth the trivial amounts of points I might lose from a couple of DVs, besides the upvotes I've gotten would offset many more DVs.

Answer (score 2):

Not explicitly, no. You have two options:

```
public interface IBase
{
    string Property1 { get; }
}

public interface IInherited : IBase
{
    void SetProperty1(string value);
}
```

Or you can just kill the compiler warning with the `new` keyword:

```
public interface IBase
{
    string Property1 { get; }
}

public interface IInherited : IBase
{
    new string Property1 { get; set; }
}
```

Unless you implement `IInherited.Property1` explicitly, `IBase` will bind to your settable implementation automatically.

Comment: On the implementation there is only 1 property called Property1. If you access the implementation via a reference to IInherited you can call getter and setter, and if you access it via IBase you can only call the getter.  But this is the required behaviour isn't it?

Comment: Yes, that's what I want. But I'll probably have to go with getter/setter methods, since it seems this can't be done...

Comment: It can be done, exactly as you are doing it... are you getting a compiler error?  What is the error?

Comment: It compiles fine. But I still want the inheritance in there. getter/setter methods aren't the worst idea ever, I just wanted to use properties for readability.

Comment: @Malki: Again, there is *no such thing as inheritance* when it comes to interfaces. It's more of...addition. You're using inheritance syntax, but it is not, strictly speaking, inheritance. Just do it the way you have it and use `new`.

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately not - properties cannot be extended as such. However, you can just hide the property by using new:

```
interface IInherited : IBase
{
    // The new is actually unnecessary (you get warnings though), hiding is automatic
    new string Property1 { get; set; }
}
```

Or, you can make your own getter and setter methods which can be overriden (good 'ol Java style):

```
interface IBase
{
    string GetProperty1();
}
interface IInherited : IBase
{
    void SetProperty1(string str);
}
```

Properties are actually converted to getter and setter methods by the compiler.

Answer (score 1):

Your code should work anyway... it just creates a complier warning because of hiding Property1.  To clear this warning mark Property1 in IInherited with the new prefix

Answer (score 0):

You can either mark the property with the "new" keyword, or you can skip the inheritance:

```
public interface IBase
{
    string Property1 { get; }
}

public interface IInherited : IBase
{
    new string Property1 { get; set; }
}
```

Or:

```
public interface IBase
{
    string Property1 { get; }
}

public interface IInherited
{
    string Property1 { get; set; }
}
```

Either way, this should work:

```
public class SomeClass : IInherited, IBase
{
    public string Property1
    {
        get
        {
            // ...
        }
        set
        {
            // ...
        }
    }
}
```

You may want to think hard before you make an inheritance chain for your interfaces, though.  Who is going to see which interface?  Would you need to cast to IInherited when passed an IBase?  If so, can you be guaranteed that you can do that cast (if you allow user created classes, then the answer is no)?  This kind of inheritance can really hurt (re)usability if you're not careful.

Answer (score 0):

I had this conversation with a couple of our Lead Devs at my work, and the conclusion that we came to is that:

- Either way technically works.
- Interfaces are all about singular purpose.

An Interface is used to define a way that any inheriting class can act. Even if your second interface shares pieces, or is even used in some of the same conditions, an interface is defined to explain how to use a class in ALL conditions related to that interface.

Additionally, classes are able to inherit multiple interfaces for this very reason. In terms of code clarity:

```
public class SomeClass : IInherited, IBase
```

The line above explicity states that SomeClass is capable of doing the actions of IInherited, and the actions of IBase, and it does not matter that some of those actions are the same. Having to crawl backwards through the interfaces to discover that IInherited extends IBase could be confusing to other developers that may look at your code in the future.

It may seem like a duplication of effort having the same values in both interfaces, but there are no assumptions made in the function of your code.